# iPhone Enterprise App Distribution - Internet Connection Required?

Tags: iphone, distribution, enter

I am trying to distribute my Enterprise Application using the method described in the Apple documentation listed here:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html

I am hitting the specially crafted itms-services URL, and it prompts me to install my application.  If I say yes, the application icon appears and it says "Loading..." and it never finishes.  I can hit my ipa file from the plist if I just bring up Safari and manually navigate to the URL.  I checked the device log and saw the following errors:

Oct  8 16:28:08 unknown imagent[23] : [Warning] Async loading of bag failed: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x1ed337c0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://init.ess.apple.com/WebObjects/VCInit.woa/wa/getBag?ix=1, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://init.ess.apple.com/WebObjects/VCInit.woa/wa/getBag?ix=1, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0x1ed32a00 "The request timed out."}
Oct  8 16:28:08 unknown imagent[23] : [Warning] Bag loading failed! Error (NSURLErrorDomain:-1001): The request timed out. http://init.ess.apple.com/WebObjects/VCInit.woa/wa/getBag?ix=1

I'm not sure if it's related, but my iOS device is on a closed network with no Internet connectivity.  Does anyone have any experience with this and know if the iOS device's inability to reach this URL could be what is making my app install hang in the "Loading..." stage?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your device needs to have access to the internet. iOS reaches out to Apple to verify that your developer certificate and profile are valid.

Comment: thank you.. i figured that was the problem.  i wonder why it doesn't do this for tethered ad hoc installs?

Comment: ahh ok.  cool.  i just found in the official apple docs where it says you have to have an internet connection too:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009979-CH1-SW17

Comment: FTA:  Network Configuration Requirements

If the devices are connected to a closed internal network, you should allow iOS devices access to these sites.

URL
 

Reason

ax.init.itunes.apple.com
 

The device obtains the current file-size limit for downloading apps over the cellular network. If this site it not reachable, installation may fail.

ocsp.apple.com
 

The device contacts this site to check the status of the distribution certificate used to sign the provisioning profile. See “Certificate Validation.”